# Choosing between Array of String (with GIN index) versus Split Rows (B-Tree Index)

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, data-modeling

I have a database which stores a column `receiver`, to signify the account which the data relates to (e.g. "Charlie"). This has however led to tons of duplication of data, as one set of data may create 3 separate rows, where the only difference is the `receiver` column.

```
|---------------------|------------------||---------------------|------------------|
|      Receiver       |       Event      ||         Date        |     Location    |
|---------------------|------------------||---------------------|------------------|
|       Alpha         |         3        ||          12         |         USA       |
|---------------------|------------------||---------------------|------------------|
|       Bravo         |         3        ||          12         |         USA       |
|---------------------|------------------||---------------------|------------------|
|       Charlie       |         3        ||          12         |         USA       |
|---------------------|------------------||---------------------|------------------|
```

While redesigning the database, I have considered using an array with a GIN index instead of the current B-Tree index on receiver. My proposed new table would look like this:

```
|-------------------------------|------------------||------------------|-------------------|
|           Receivers           |       Event      ||      Date        |     Location      |
|-------------------------------|------------------||------------------|-------------------|
| ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"] |         3        ||       12         |         USA       |
|-------------------------------|------------------||------------------|-------------------|
```

95% of all queries currently are of the form: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Receiver = Alpha`

**Additionally, the table currently contains over 4 billion rows and this would cut it down to under 2 billion rows.**

Which option is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* use arrays, but a normalized data model where `event` and `receiver` are two different tables. The relationship between the tables should be implemented by a foreign key constraint on `receiver`.

The tables would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE occurrence (
   occurrence_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   event integer NOT NULL,
   date integer NOT NULL,
   location text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE receiver (
   receiver_id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   receiver_name text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE log_entry (
   occurrence_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES occurrence,
   receiver_id   bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES receiver,
   PRIMARY KEY (occurrence_id, receiver_id)
);
```

A log entry references an event occurrence and a receiver.

You'd query like

```
SELECT r.receiver_name,
       o.event,
       o.date,
       o.location
FROM occurrence AS o
   JOIN log_entry AS l USING (occurrence_id)
   JOIN receiver AS r USING (receiver_id)
WHERE /* your conditions */;
```

Comment: I believe insertion into 2 tables at our rate (up to 50-100K/s) + FK constraint will lead to performance degradation for insertions. By splitting this current table into 2 tables, we would likely be doing 3X as many insertions (average # of receivers is 2).

Comment: Additionally, we do not need the FK constraint for our operations, as this is a append-only log system. Do you believe the FK would improve the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Receiver = 'Alpha'`?

Comment: The query might actually become slower - only an experiment would show. It would only reduce the data duplication you were concerned about. If this is just for logging, I would probably live with the data duplication because that way the `INSERT` is fastest. But then, most of the time, it is a mistake to log into a database rather than to a text file. It makes logging slow and creates large databases. You can later load log files into the database to analyze them.

Comment: It is not just for logging, all of our analytics are run on the data, so querying is #1 priority. We can take a hit on insert speed if querying can be improved.

Can you help me understand how data duplication is prevented by having seperate tables? There would still be 3 records in the events table.

Comment: I have added sample table definitions to the answer, maybe that explains what I have in mind.

Comment: I see what you mean, to model it as a Many-to-Many relationship. To note, receiver names are unique.

There are some receivers who have over a billion events, any queries on them will lead to large joins, which I believe will hurt performance. I will add this schema to the test list for benchmarking.

Comment: If you add `WHERE` conditions that reduce the number of `occurrence` entries you match, PostgreSQL will apply these filters before joining. But it still could be slower than a single denormalized table. In analytical queries a denormalized table usually wins.